# How can I toggle an output using the same input pulse?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I need to make a contraption that takes a pulse and toggles a switch from on to off. Then when the pulse happens again, I need it to turn from off to on.

Comment: What's the question? What is the trouble you are having in attempting to achieve what you've described?

Answer (score 6):

The Minecraft Wiki has redstone circuits that can handle what you're looking for. More specifically, you'll need a [T Flip-Flop](https://minecraft.wiki/w/T_Flip-Flop#T_Flip-Flop):

[image: T-Flip-Flop]

Comment: Just a note, there are designs that use pistons that are more space efficient, but they may not work with the latest patch.  Time to test!  Yep, still work.

Answer (score 0):

turn the pulse into 1 tic pulse then conect it to a sticky piston that has a redstone block on it.

input pulse  -->      block  repeater -->   piston> redstone block    -->  output pulse
                         ^
                       piston

the arrows (-->) are redstone dust

Comment: With just text, it's really hard to visualize the design you're proposing. Can you include a screenshot of some sort so it's easier to tell what you mean?

Answer (score -2):

What you are looking for is a t-flip flop. Just search Google, you should be able to find one that suits your needs.

Comment: If you're just going to say "search google", it's not a very interesting answer. Provide details yourself, that's what makes a quality answer.